# datakeynames in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have gridview having a

```
 DataKeyNames="FilterId,ItemId"
```

field.How can i get each values in both fields in

```
 gdv_RowEditing
```

event.i tried

```
 protected void gdv_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
     string a = gdv.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value[0].ToString(); 
     string b = gdv.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value[1].ToString();
    }
```

but it shows error like

```
'cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object'
```

Comment: cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
IOrderedDictionary datakeyNames = gdv.DataKeys[0].Values;
string a = datakeyNames["FilterId"].ToString();
string b = datakeyNames["ItemId"].ToString();
```

Please note that you have to import `System.Collections.Specialized`

Answer (score 1):

This error cause because you are using

```
   gdv.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value[0].ToString();
```

Here Value is type of object so you can not indexing on object.

to get data key value use Values instead of Value like this

```
  gdv.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Values[0].ToString();
```

Hope this helps..